# Generating timeline with R package timelineS

Tags: r, timeline

My R script looks like this

```
if (!require("timelineS")) install.packages("timelineS")
library('timelineS')

myevents <- read.csv(
text = "MS1.1.1,2021-12-01
MS1.1.2,2022-03-01
MS1.1.3,2022-09-01
MS1.1.4,2022-09-01
MS1.1.5,2022-09-01
MS1.1.6,2022-11-01
MS1.1.7,2023-03-01
MS1.1.8,2023-09-01
MS1.1.9,2023-09-01",
sep=",",header=F)
head(myevents)
class(myevents)
timelineS(myevents)
```

and I get the error "*Fehler in min(event.dates) - buffer.days :
nicht-numerisches Argument für binären Operator*".
I cannot figure out where is my mistake.

Thank you for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
?timelineS
myevents$V2 <- as.Date(myevents$V2)
timelineS(myevents)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case, my data frame had the event date first and the event second. The reverse order is needed. I fixed my data frame this way:

```
raw_df <- read_tsv("2022_12.tsv") #from readr package

# reverse order of columns
my_df <- data.frame(raw_df$Events, raw_df$Event_Dates)
names(my_df) <- sort(names(raw_df), decreasing = T)
```